# Jdbctemplate connection issue with ejb with java api

Tags: jndi

I have spring core api, which is working fine on server start up and am getting the data from oracle database.

When trying to invoke the JAVAapi through ejb application I'm getting below issues. on jndi connection

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; 
nested exception is org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!;
- nested throwable: (javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: a56092b:f14d:598d7b69:65 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >);
- nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!; 
- nested throwable: (javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: a56092b:f14d:598d7b69:65 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >))
```

Comment: can you paste the relevant code?

Comment: if (m_objJdbcTemplate == null) {
   OracleDataSource l_objOracleDataSource = RuleITSettings.getM_objSourceOracleDS();
   DataSource l_objDataSource = null;
   try {
    if (l_objOracleDataSource != null) {
     m_objJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(l_objOracleDataSource);
    } else {
     Context l_objContext = new InitialContext();
     l_objDataSource = (DataSource) l_objContext.lookup(RuleITSettings.getM_sJndiName());
     m_objJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(l_objDataSource);
    }
   } catch (NamingException exNamingException) {
   } catch (Exception exException) {
   }

Comment: code in question, not comment